# A collection of interconnected futures in async Rust w/ tokio

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

### Problem statement

I'd like to implement a directed acyclic computation graph framework in async Rust, i.e. an interconnected graph of computation "nodes", each of which takes inputs from predecessor nodes and produces outputs for successor nodes. I was planning to implement this by spawning a collection of `Future`s, one for each computation node, while allowing dependencies among futures. However, in implementing this framework using `async` I've become hopelessly lost in compiler errors.

### Minimal example

Here's an attempt at a minimal example of what I want to do. There's a single input list of floats `values`, and the task is to make a new list `output` where `output[i] = values[i] + output[i - 2]`. This is what I've tried:

```rust
use std::sync;

fn some_complicated_expensive_fn(val1: f32, val2: f32) -> f32 {
    val1 + val2
}

fn example_async(values: &Vec<f32>) -> Vec<f32> {
    let runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();

    let join_handles = sync::Arc::new(sync::Mutex::new(Vec::<tokio::task::JoinHandle<f32>>::new()));
    for (i, value) in values.iter().enumerate() {
        let future = {
            let join_handles = join_handles.clone();
            async move {
                if i < 2 {
                    *value
                } else {
                    let prev_value = join_handles.lock().unwrap()[i - 2].await.unwrap();
                    some_complicated_expensive_fn(*value, prev_value)
                }
            }
        };
        join_handles.lock().unwrap().push(runtime.spawn(future));
    }
    join_handles
        .lock()
        .unwrap()
        .iter_mut()
        .map(|join_handle| runtime.block_on(join_handle).unwrap())
        .collect()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_example() {
        let values = vec![1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.];
        println!("{:?}", super::example_async(&values));
    }
}
```

I get errors about the unlocked `Mutex` not being `Send`:

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> sim/src/compsim/runtime.rs:23:51
   |
23 |         join_handles.lock().unwrap().push(runtime.spawn(future));
   |                                                   ^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
   |
   = help: within `impl Future`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Vec<tokio::task::JoinHandle<f32>>>`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
  --> sim/src/compsim/runtime.rs:18:38
   |
18 |                     let prev_value = join_handles.lock().unwrap()[i - 2].await.unwrap();
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ first, await occurs here, with `join_handles.lock().unwrap()` maybe used later...
note: `join_handles.lock().unwrap()` is later dropped here
  --> sim/src/compsim/runtime.rs:18:88
   |
18 |                     let prev_value = join_handles.lock().unwrap()[i - 2].await.unwrap();
   |                                      ----------------------------                      ^
   |                                      |
   |                                      has type `std::sync::MutexGuard<'_, Vec<tokio::task::JoinHandle<f32>>>` which is not `Send`
help: consider moving this into a `let` binding to create a shorter lived borrow
  --> sim/src/compsim/runtime.rs:18:38
   |
18 |                     let prev_value = join_handles.lock().unwrap()[i - 2].await.unwrap();
   |                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This makes sense, and I see in the [Tokio docs](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/shared-state#holding-a-mutexguard-across-an-await) that you can use a `tokio::task::Mutex` instead, but a) I'm not sure how, and b) I'm wondering if there's a better overall approach that I'm missing. Help greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: With only skimming through your code, you don't do anything asynchronous. `rayon` is preferred for such cases.

Comment: What's the point in parallelizing things while each value has to wait nonetheless for the previous value?

Comment: It's an idealized version of the problem I encounter when attempting to implement the main problem statement, where the dependency graph could be much more complicated. Also, there are two independent chains of execution, so parallelism is possible: the even entries and the odd entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that you can't cross an await point with `join_handle` being locked, which is because the task might be picked up by a different thread after `.await`, and a lock must be locked and unlocked in the same thread. You could resolve this by making the lock shorter-lived, e.g. by keeping each handle in an `Option`, [taking](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take) it before await. But then you run into the issue that awaiting a `JoinHandle` *consumes* it - you receive the value that was returned by the task, and you lose the handle, so you can't return it to the vector. (This is a consequence of Rust values having a single owner, so once the handle passes the value to you, it no longer has it and has become useless.)

A handle basically works like a one-shot channel for the result of the spawned task. Since you need the results in one more place, you can separately create a vector of [one-shot channels](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html) that keeps another copy of results, which can be awaited by tasks that need them.

```
pub fn example_async(values: &[f32]) -> Vec<f32> {
    let runtime = tokio::runtime::Runtime::new().unwrap();

    let (txs, rxs): (Vec<_>, Vec<_>) = (0..values.len())
        .map(|_| {
            let (tx, rx) = tokio::sync::oneshot::channel();
            (Mutex::new(Some(tx)), Mutex::new(Some(rx)))
        })
        .unzip();
    let txs = Arc::new(txs);
    let rxs = Arc::new(rxs);

    let mut join_handles = vec![];
    for (i, value) in values.iter().copied().enumerate() {
        let txs = Arc::clone(&txs);
        let rxs = Arc::clone(&rxs);
        let future = async move {
            let result = if i < 2 {
                value
            } else {
                let prev_rx = rxs[i - 2].lock().unwrap().take().unwrap();
                let prev_value = prev_rx.await.unwrap();
                some_complicated_expensive_fn(value, prev_value)
            };
            let tx = txs[i].lock().unwrap().take().unwrap();
            tx.send(result).unwrap(); // here you'd use result.clone() for non-Copy result
            result
        };
        join_handles.push(runtime.spawn(future));
    }
    join_handles
        .into_iter()
        .map(|handle| runtime.block_on(handle).unwrap())
        .collect()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c5e76ecfffa77ff08eea580532441007)

Comment: Fantastic, this is a great approach.

Comment: @JoshBurkart I've now edited the answer to use the more efficient one-shot channels, which should be sufficient for this use case.